# don't get data-id value from seceond <td > to last <td>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to get `data-id` value from all `td`. But I only get the `data-id` value from the first `td`. Why am I not getting `data-id` value from second `td` to last `td` ?

This is my blade template code:

```
@foreach ($types as $type)
                    <tr>
                       <td>{{$type->name}}</td>
                       <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"  
                            id="edit_type" data-id="{{ $type->id }}"> 
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a> <a 
                            href=""><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                             </a> 
                         </td>
                             </tr>
                  @endforeach
This is my jquery code: 

      $('#edit_type').click(function(){
         var type_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
         console.log(type_id);

   });
```

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

That might be, because HTML defines IDs as a once-per-page name. So you can never have multiple elements on a single page with the same `id="xxx"` attribute.

As a result you should never use a fixed ID if you iterate over anything (like your `@foreach`)! Use a className instead:

```
                  @foreach ($types as $type)
                    <tr>
                       <td>{{$type->name}}</td>
                       <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"  
                            class="edit_type" data-id="{{ $type->id }}"> 
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a> <a 
                            href=""><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                             </a> 
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

with:

```js
$('.edit_type').click(function(){
    var type_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(type_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you have:

```
      $('#edit_type').click(function(){
         var type_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
         console.log(type_id);

      });
```

The `#` is an `id` selector, so the code under the hood stops its search when the first match was found, because an `id` (which stands for unique identifier) is safe to be assumed to be unique. If that's not the case in your situation, then you have invalid HTML, which is your main problem.

Technically a selector of `$([id=edit_type])` would work, because it would be an attribute selector, but you should do something like this instead:

```
@foreach ($types as $type)
                    <tr>
                       <td>{{$type->name}}</td>
                       <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"  
                            class="edit_type" data-id="{{ $type->id }}"> 
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i></a> <a 
                            href=""><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                             </a> 
                         </td>
                             </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

```
      $('.edit_type').click(function(){
         var type_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
         console.log(type_id);

   });
```